# invalid covariant return type for templated child class

Tags: c++, templates, virtual, covariance

I have a child class that inherits from a parent class, but the child also picks up a template argument. Both classes have a 'clone' function that just calls their copy constructor. I want to make the copy virtual so that the child class will always call it's own copy.

Here is a simplified version of the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Parent
{
public:
    virtual Parent foo() { cout << "Parent Foo\n"; return *this; }
};

template <class T>
class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    Child<T> foo() { cout << "Child Foo\n"; return *this; }
};

int main()
{
    Child<int> c;

    c.foo();

    return 0;
}
```

It seems that the Child class should be covariant with the Parent class. What am I missing? Is there a way to still keep the virtual function and the template? Thanks.

**EDIT**

Perhaps my previous example was too simple. Here is an expanded simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Parent
{
public:
    Parent(){}
    virtual Parent clone() const { return Parent(*this); }
private:
    Parent( Parent const& cpy ) { };
};

template <class T>
class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    Child(){}
    Child<T> clone() const { return Child<T>(*this); }
private:
    Child( Child<T> const& cpy ) {};
};

int main()
{
    Child<int> c;
    Parent* pc = &c;
    pc->clone();

    return 0;
}
```

I would like the copy to always be an actual copy of the class by making copy virtual.
I wanted to avoid returning a pointer, but it looks like I will be forced to return pointers to avoid the slicing problem mentioned by Dieter Lücking.

Comment: Try returning by pointer or reference instead of by value.

Comment: The concept of covariant return type applies only to pointer or reference return types. There's no covariance for "by value" returns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The types Parent and Child are not covariant, but Parent& and Child& are.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Parent
{
public:
    virtual Parent& foo() = 0;
};

template <class T>
class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    Child& foo() { cout << "Child Foo\n"; return *this; }
};

int main()
{
    Child<int> c;
    Parent& parent = c.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

From 10.3.7 Virtual functions

> The return type of an overriding function shall be either identical to
>   the return type of the overridden function or covariant with the
>   classes of the functions. If a function D::f overrides a function
>   B::f, the return types of the functions are covariant if they satisfy
>   the following criteria:
>
> — both are pointers to classes, both are
>   lvalue references to classes, or both are rvalue references to
>   classes112
>
> — the class in the return type of B::f is the same class as
>   the class in the return type of D::f, or is an unambiguous and
>   accessible direct or indirect base class of the class in the return
>   type of D::f
>
> — both pointers or references have the same
>   cv-qualification and the class type in the return type of D::f has the
>   same cv-qualification as or less cv-qualification than the class type
>   in the return type of B::f.

Comment: Will I still get local scope forwarding if I return by reference?

Comment: To clarify, the `clone` function simply does `{ return Child(*this); }`

Comment: @CoryBeutler It is pointless to return a Child, getting sliced to  Parent during return.

Comment: See edit. It looks like I will need to return a pointer rather than a reference in order to avoid the slicing. I will make this the correct answer, though, since it does answer my initial question perfectly.